# Select all recursive value with one query SQLite

Tags: sql, recursion

i have some another case :

first I created a table:

```
 CREATE TABLE tree(
     id_tree integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     id_boss TEXT,
     id_child TEXT,
     answ TEXT);
```

insert some values :

```
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('1','8','T');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('1',null,'F');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('8','P1','T');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('8','2','F');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('2','P2','T');
 INSERT INTO tree(id_boss,id_child,answ) VALUES('2','P3','F');
```

and execute query:

```
  WITH RECURSIVE
  ancestors(id, answ) AS (
  VALUES('P3', 'T')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tree.id_boss, tree.answ
  FROM tree JOIN ancestors ON tree.id_child = ancestors.id
  )
  SELECT id FROM ancestors WHERE answ = 'T';
```

the result is :

```
  P3
  1
```

that for `P3` , and i want to make list with all recursive value , so it will be like this :

```
   1 --- // P3
   1 --- // P1
   8 --- // P1
   2 --- // P2
   1 --- // P2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this somewhere near what you are looking for?

```
WITH seed (id, answ) as ( VALUES('P3', 'T') )
   , ancestors1(id, answ) AS (
        select * from seed
        UNION ALL
        SELECT tree.id_boss, tree.answ
        FROM tree, ancestors1 where tree.id_child = ancestors1.id
     )
   , ancestors2(id, answ) AS (
        select * from seed
        UNION ALL
        SELECT tree.id_boss, tree.answ
        FROM tree, ancestors2 where tree.id_child = ancestors2.id
    )
select id from (
    select * from ancestors1
    union all
    select * from ancestors2
);
```

I had to rephrase certain things inorder to get thenm to compile with db2 (remove RECURSIVE, and use implicit join)

Comment: sorry , but is not work , i want to select all recursive = `P1` , `P2`, `P3` , not just `P3` value.